# How to customize with the titlesec package?

Tags: titlesec

[image: Example (The red line is only to indicate the alignment)]

How to implement with the package titlesec in the preamble to maintain the same vertical alignment and numbering?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @cfr I'm not sure your comment is helpful (independent of your allergy). This kind of format isn't trivial to achieve in standard LaTeX.

Comment: @AlanMunn I know. But presumably the OP is using a class or package which provides the 'required vertical alignment and numbering'. Otherwise, it would not be a question of keeping that the same, but of changing it to that. So if loading `titlesec` undoes that formatting, then I don't see why you'd load that package. Surely the simple solution is not to load it? I assume the OP wants to load it for some reason - maybe to change the fonts of the headings or something. But we need to know what the package is wanted for (and how the current format is got) to say the best way to do it.